# How to create HelpContents file in Winform application c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed my Winform application.
Now I want to add some Help section in my application

How to add HelpContents section in my Winform application???

Like;
at left side some treeView is there and as I click on TreeView item it will open my txt file at the right side of treeView where I drop one panel there.

Comment: The best way is to create help for your project is having a compiled HTML (.chm) file. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705836/how-can-i-create-chm-files-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: One more duplicate pribably:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158901/integrating-help-into-winforms-application

Comment: You developed your application and you can't read a text file? Or do you need to integrate chm help?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the few files and if you know the place than you can make a treeview with the help of the site http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview.

and on double click property read the file by

string[] file1=File.readalllines();

put a listbox or text box on right and then  write down that file on the listbox or textbox by using

for textbox(use multiline) you can directly read and add to the textbox using

```
textdata.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
```

for listbox

```
for(int i=0;i<file1.lenght;i++)
listbox.items.add(file1[i]);
```